# Implementation of Foreign keys in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I wrote this model for my app

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import FrontendUsers
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Jit(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(FrontendUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now() )
```

In views I have defined a function which will populate table of Jits with indormation taken from user.

### views.py

```
def new_post (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        value = request.POST.get('value')
        if value != '' and value :
            author_id = int(request.POST['user_id'])



            jit = Jit.objects.create(value = value,author=author_id)

            jit.save()
            return redirect('feed')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'There was some problem writing your jit.')
    return redirect('feed')
```

### Error

> Cannot assign "15": "Jit.author" must be a "FrontendUsers" instance.

In simple words I am trying to add author_id to Jit's table so that both tables can be connected.

Comment: How is `FrontendUsers` defined? Is AUTH_USER_MODEL set to FrontendUsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of these ways, but second one is better as it doesn't fetch author from database:

```
author = FrontendUsers.objects.get(id=author_id)
jit = Jit.objects.create(value = value,author=author)
```

or

```
jit = Jit.objects.create(value = value,author_id=author_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like

`jit = Jit.objects.create(value = value,author_id=author_id)`

Answer (score -1):

Your are converting the user instace in ant int.

I think you should be using a form to achieve what you want. Try something like this, it works for me.

```
def new_post (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if your_form.is_valid():
            value = your_form.cleaned_data["value"]
            if value:
                result = your_form.save(commit=False)
                user = Jit.objects.get(id=value)
                result.author = user
                result.save()
```